# How to display a custom page for 400 error message for WordPress website hosted on a NGINX server?

Tags: errors, server, nginx

When I try to access the below URL in my WordPress website on the NGINX server it's showing a 400 Bad Request error. I want to show a custom page whenever this error message occurs.
For example, when I try to access the below URL it's showing 400 Bad Request nginx error page.
Here is the URL I am entering to generate the error.

https://staging-vdt2zeq-h5nh2nj2vb2xg.au.platformsh.site/wp-content/plugins/..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2f..%2fetc%2fhosts

What will be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

To display a custom error page for 400 errors on an Nginx server, you can try and use a custom error page. This could be an HTML page with the content you want to show to users when they hit a 400 error.

Once you have created the custom error page, you will need to edit your Nginx configuration file. This is usually located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` or a similar location, depending on your server setup.

You would then add an error_page directive inside the server block for your site, pointing to the location of your custom error page. It would look something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    
    # Rest of your configuration...

    error_page 400 /path/to/your/error400.html;
    location = /path/to/your/error400.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```

In the above configuration, replace `/path/to/your/error400.html` with the actual path to your custom error page. You might need to restart your Nginix service to make these changes work.

Comment: Can I do it by modifying a .platform.app.yml file?
I have added this code in my .platform.app.yml file as:
errors:
  400:
      redirect: /error/400.html

Comment: I have put the above code in the web section of my .platform.app.yml file as:
`# The configuration of app when it is exposed to the web.
web:
    locations:
        "/":
            # The public directory of the app, relative to its root.
            root: "wordpress"
            # Other Code
            # Other Code
            # Other Code
            # Other Code
            errors:
                400:
                    redirect: /terms-of-use
`